# nodejs cannot perform http post with autorization header

Tags: node.js, rest

this is the request i want to perform:

```
POST /v1/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: api.sandbox.paypal.com
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: en_US
Authorization: Basic cGF5cGFsaWQ6c2VjcmV0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials
```

I tried it in nodejs using this code:

```
paypalSignIn = function(){
var username = process.env.PAYPALID;
var password = process.env.PAYPALSECRET;
var auth = 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(username + ':' + password).toString('base64');
// new Buffer() is deprecated from v6

// auth is: 'Basic VGVzdDoxMjM='
 var post_data = querystring.stringify({
      'grant_type' : 'client_credentials',
  });
var header = {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Authorization': auth, 'Accept-Language': 'en_US'};
const options = {
  hostname: 'api.sandbox.paypal.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/v1/oauth2/token',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: header,
}

var post_req = http.request(options, function(res) {
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
      console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
  });
});
 post_req.write(post_data);
 post_req.end();
```

}

Unfortunately i'm getting the following error:

> Error: socket hang up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [`https` module](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback) (it's not enough to set port 443, you have to use the  HTTPS protocol to connect to an HTTPS endpoint).

I also noticed you didn't set the `Content-Type` header. It depends on the API, but that may cause problems for you too.

Finally, I'd consider using a library that wraps `http`/`https` like [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch), [bent](https://github.com/mikeal/bent), or [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) for this rather than the standard library directly. It can handle things like writing to the socket, setting the `Content-Length` header, etc.